# Controlling JavaScript slideshow with keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I want to move my slider index with my keyboard.

The current slideshow can be navigated with the built in buttons, but i want to be able to use my keyboard to move forward or back. I have linked my keyboard with switch cast (`37` for `left`) (`39` for `right`), but nothing happens.

Here is all my JS

```
var slideIndex = 1;

showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

document.onkeydown = function(n) {
     switch (e.keyCode) {
         case 37:
            //left
            slideIndex--;
            break;
         case 39:
            //right
            slideIndex++;
            break;          
    }
}
```

Comment: Just changing `slideIndex` isn't enough, you need to also call `showSlides(slideIndex)` afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the variable name in `document.onkeydown`.
2. Make sure you call the function to display slides, when the current slide changes.

**E.g.:**

```
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                //left
                e.preventDefault();
                slideIndex--;
                showSlides(slideIndex);
                break;
            case 39:
                //right
                e.preventDefault();
                slideIndex++;
                showSlides(slideIndex);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This clear up a lot of my confusion. One last thing, how would I call the function to display the slides, I’m new to JS, sorry

Comment: See in the code block I'm already calling it currentSlide(slideIndex--); or currentSlide(slideIndex++);

Comment: OH! I overlooked that my fault. Thanks so much for your help man, ur amazing!

Comment: unfortunately, after implementing the changes, it still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: I updated the code above, added e.preventDefault();. Try now.  
And sorry, onkeydown was correct.

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing, I have my JS in the same file as my html, is that alright?

Comment: As long as all your JS is within `<script></script>` tags, yes.

Comment: Damn, I’m not sure what’s wrong with it, everything looks right.

Comment: Try call `currentSlide(...)` within your code with various values. Make sure that it's working correctly. Because the  `document.onkeydown` part should work.

Comment: E.g. at the end of your code add this:  
`setTimeout(function() { currentSlide(slideIndex--) }, 1000);`  
`setTimeout(function() { currentSlide(slideIndex++) }, 2000);`  
Then reload the document. Make sure your slider goes to previous after 1 second, then back after another second.

Comment: i added an alert to the left key and it works, so the keys work

Comment: Are you sure the showSlides function works correctly? Do the built in buttons call it or something else?

Comment: Yea the buttons work, they just use the ++ and — for the slider index

Comment: That's weird. They have to somehow call showSlides function anyway. I changed the code in the answer. Try now. But, I'm afraid, that's all I can think of.